# Android Fragment onCreateAnimator never shows exit

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I'm trying to manage my fragment animations with the onCreateAnimator method.  The problem is the enter parameter is always true.  So how do I tell when I've called hide() in my fragment transaction?  Ideally I would like to allow the animation to play then remove the fragment.

```
@Override
public Animator onCreateAnimator(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim)
{
    final int animatorId = (enter) ? R.animator.menu_in : R.animator.menu_out;

    if(enter){
        // This prints on add, show, and hide.
        Log.i("tag", "enter");  
    }
    else{
        // This prints if I call remove(), but the animation doesn't play.
        Log.i("tag", "exit");
    }
}
```

My Fragment transaction

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

SideMenu menu = (SideMenu)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("SideMenu");
if(menu != null){
     ft.hide(menu);
     ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same issue.